# Rails not saving in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I want to get a view count for every time a photo is viewed.  This is my show method, not sure why this doesn't work, seems pretty straight forward.  The branch is called every time, but the database is not bing update...

```
  def show
    if current_user.nil? || @photo.profile != current_user.profile
      @photo.views += 1
      @photo.save!
    end
    render layout: 'layouts/photo'
  end
```

Comment: Solved the problem by creating a local variable and doing a .find(@photo.id) call, but I would still like to know why the referenced variable was not updating the DB, seems wonky to me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `@profile` is simply not specified.
You may want to do something like the following:

```
def show
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  if @profile && current_user.nil? || @photo.profile != current_user.profile
    @profile.views += 1
    @profile.save
  end
  render layout: 'layouts/photo'
end
```

Besides that it's probably best to use a gem for that matter. I suggest [`impressionist`](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist). It will handle the most important stuff for you and block bots. It also offers additional features you may want.

Comment: I don't think that is it, ATprofile is actually created in a before_action method not in this example.  So being that I do have an ATprofile defined, I am back to still wondering why.